# django values_list() and image reverse foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a problem with the images, they are not displayed in the template, can someone help me with some solution

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    myshop = models.ForeignKey(MyShop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shop_product")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_image")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images',
                          validators=[validate_image_file_extension, validate_file_size,
                                      FileExtensionValidator(['JPEG', 'JPG', 'PNG'])])

{% for product in products %}  
    {% for image in product.product_image.all %}
        {% if image.is_feature %}
            <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="" width="80" height="80">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}



products = Product.prod_obj.select_related(
        'myshop'
    ).filter(id__in=product_ids).values_list('myshop', 'title', 'description', 'product_image', named=True)
```

Comment: Don't use `.values_list`: it removes the model logic layer, and thus as a result, you can indeed no longer access `.url`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [**`.values_list()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) or [**`.values()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values): it removes the model logic layer, and thus as a result, you can indeed no longer access `.url`.

Query with:

```
products = Product.prod_obj.select_related('myshop').prefetch_related(
    'product_image'
).filter(id__in=product_ids)
```

For more information, see this [article on *(over)use of `.values()`*](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html) I wrote.